# Eclipse plugin - Implement own contents assistant in pydev-editor

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, pydev, content-assist

I am trying to implement Eclipse plugin - Content Assistant in pydev-editor.
Opening python file with pydev-editor, and when i type specific character, for example "MY_Defined_Data(" then i want to show some value list in there.

I tried with org.eclipse.ui.editor, org.eclipse.ui.genericeditor.contentAssistProcessors....
But this is possible when it opens with Generic Editor..
Setting as follows, and choose file extension as "py".
[Plugin template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rj7nI.png)
[File_exetension](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KieS9.png)

Is there any ways to implement this?

Thanks.

Comment: Are pydev-editor and the Generic Editor related?

Comment: It is totally different area. I just thought when it share "file-extension: py"(Generic and Pydev Editor), it works both editor. But it seems that it depends on which Editor opened.

Comment: Then,,, how to override the pydev Editor`s contents assist?,,